# Match rows between datasets with noisy unstructured data and no unique identifier

Tags: sql, mapreduce, dataset, pattern-matching, data-mining

Given 2 datasets, one of which is extremely unstructured and noisy, and another which is well structured and complete - does there exist a software tool, API or framework that I can use to match rows in the unstructured dataset to those in the structured dataset given that neither set contains any unique identifier?  Possibly with the ability to produce some sort of confidence score that the rows are a match.

That is basically the question, but there's more info below if interested:

I have 2 datasets. Both consist of user information, containing names, addresses, contact details and other miscellaneous information about a user.

Dataset #1 is unformatted, unordered, undelimited, noisy (missing values, unconventional data, i.e. a phone number could be +XX (XX) XXX XXX, the next row's phone number could be XXXXXXXXXX). With the only convenience afforded being that each user record is at least on its own row.

Dataset #2 is augmented across roughly 80 separate datasets, however each dataset although not uniform to each other, is well formatted and data is well delineated meaning I can likely normalise these into 1 logical dataset - for the purpose of this question, consider this one set.

Every record in Dataset #1 is contained in Dataset #2 - the problem is there is no unique identifiers and Dataset #1 is noisy and unstructured.

Answer (score 0):

No answers so far so I'll contribute the results of research I've done since asking this. The field this kind of problem belongs to is Record Linkage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage, that is matching records between 2 data sets where this is no shared unique id between the records.

I've found this software http://fril.sourceforge.net/ for Record Linkage, that incorporates a range of Distance Metrics into its linking algorithms so that confidence and acceptance levels can be set when matching between the left and right sides, e.g., q-gram distance can be used for matching different formats of storing names as the order of the "q-grams" (subsets of the given strings) does not matter, therefore "John Doe" and "Doe, John" will give a high score. Soundex algorithms can be used for overcoming common misspellings in the name fields as well, i.e. "John Doe" and "Jon Doe".  For other types of data an edit distance or other distance metric can be used.

Based on the results of each distance metric, a confidence level is calculated, and a match is made providing the confidence level is equal or higher than the acceptance level set.

This field and software will likely overcome the problem of the differences in the format of the stored data, I'll likely have to do additional work structuring Dataset #1 mentioned above before I can feed it into this kind of system.